# Android: error adding frament to the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager

There are some peculiarities on android that i hate like a hell...

The issues around `isFinishing()` of activity are the worst.
I do understand some actions are not allowed after or during this process, but the only way we have to check it is by this method, and somethimes it isn't effective let me show a very simple example and please guide me in how to solve it with the best practices:

I want to add a fragment to my screen

```
if(!this.isFinishing() && getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(VerifyIdentityDialog.CHALLENGE_DIALOG_TAG) == null)
try {
      new VerifyIdentityDialog((ChallengeRequiredException) e, new DefaultVerifyIdentityListener())
              .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), VerifyIdentityDialog.CHALLENGE_DIALOG_TAG);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
      Crashlytics.logException(e1);
  }
```

This code is running only on `MainThread` it explicitly checks if the activity is finishing before try but still i get around 2% of users running into exception on it...

The exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

[Avoid pasting long stack trace since it is a default android exception and the related code is mentioned above]

1- Before i added `!this.isFinishing()` in the if, the exception was way more frequent, but still didn't solve it 100%
2- according to Crashlytics 97% are on background when it hapens, so I THINK the code starts, the user goes to background then it simple crashes

the question is...
how is the proper way to solve it... i hate catching exception for predictable situations

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check whether the FragmentManager has saved its state via [isStateSaved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager#isstatesaved) - you should only `show()` your dialog if the state is not saved.